# save large DataFrame as json in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

For some time I've been using following construct to save data frame which I need as JSONL (single file where each object is a separate line JSON):

```
myRDD.coalesce(1).toDF().write.format("json").save("s3://bucket/"+"itr_"+dateTimestampStringValue)
```

it was executed as a part of job I ran on AWS EMR instance and produced a file part_0000 in folder s3://bucket/itr_09022021_0825 (example timestamp). EMR instance I run has Spark 2.4.6 on it:

> Release label:emr-5.31.0 Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.10.0
> Applications:Hive 2.3.7, Spark 2.4.6, Zeppelin 0.8.2, HBase 1.4.13,
> Hue 4.7.1

Currently, I face a situation when the cluster can't output a JSON file and fail with OutOfMemory for the obvious reason of too much data converted in JSON.

Is there any way to do one of following

- somehow 'stream' data from each worker to a single file on s3 - so each worker append its part of data to same file, or,
- alternatively, each worker produce its own file and then all these json files are merged together (order of objects in final as well as in the intermediate files is of course not important, they all just need to be there)

I guess this is a very ordinary thing but I'm stuck trying to understand how to overcome memory limit and stream all data into a single file without bicycle invention

Comment: I found the problem for this issue - I was operating on dataframe from mysql datasource but there were 2 issues: all jdbc data was supposed to flow as temp view edgesDfInit.createOrReplaceTempView(edgesTable)
and second, there was no caching happening up until the write which was killing performance